# Is it possible to use HTTPS/SSL in Wakanda Cloud?

Tags: wakanda

My application will capture private customer data, requiring secure access for my clients.

Is  it possible to use HTTPS/SSL in Wakanda Cloud?

Comment: NP. However, it was suggested to me 'today'... by Wakanda Customer Service that... "that's a great question... post it on StackOverflow". ;-)

Comment: @user1598400: You should tell Wakanda customer support that they should really train their staff about what is on topic here.

Comment: I see that HTTPS is on the [roadmap](https://trello.com/c/5wbp8Zt1) for Wakanda cloud but i dont know when it will be added.

Comment: Totally understand, Jon and Ken. Appreciate the feedback. I was aware of the Trello roadmap, Tim... but thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS/SSL is not a *current feature* of Wakanda Cloud. However, HTTPS/SSL is a feature of Wakanda Server when you [host it yourself](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Wakanda-Server-Reference-Guide/Administrating-Wakanda-Server/Configuring-secure-connections-SSLTLS.300-952181.en.html).

The [Wakanda Cloud Roadmap](https://trello.com/b/0DRtt76j/wakanda-cloud-roadmap) is on Trello, which lists [SSL/HTTPS Support](https://trello.com/c/5wbp8Zt1) as a **`proposed feature`**.

You can vote on **`proposed features`** at Trello.

You can also submit additional feature requests at [Trello](https://trello.com/b/0DRtt76j/wakanda-cloud-roadmap)

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is available in the Wakanda Cloud.  I have a medium instance using HTTPS right now.